# Compute the image and the kernel of a morphism from $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ to itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $d:\mathbb{Q}^{2}\to\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ be the morphism given by
$$d=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I would like to know what is the kernel and the image of this map. My guess is that, in both cases, is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you guessing?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you write down one non-zero element in the kernel? Then the kernel is  just the span of this element. Similarly can you write down one non-zero element in the image? The image is just the span of this element. Prove this using rank-nullity.